# Access USB device with command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, usb

If I connect a Camera or Phone with my Windows 7 machine via USB, it shows up in explorer with a name e.g. `Canon SD110` or `Nexus 5`. How can I open a command prompt and change directory to this device. For lettered drives, I can just type `D:` `F:` etc.

Comment: i guess this is a device that comes up under "portable devices"? there's a thread on it here but no real answer  there http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows/105923-force-windows-assign-drive-letter-portable-device.html   i hope somebody here knows

Answer (score 1):

USB Mass Storage Force apps are available(require root). Or you could enable your IOT menus to get into usb settings.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to connect your device in *mass storage mode*.

Comment: wouldn't it be a mass storage device if you can get it up in explorer? and how would you make it a mass storage device if it isn't coming up as that?

Comment: Android offers a choice between PTP (Camera) & MTP (Media). No option to connect as mass storage.

Comment: @barlop: nope, it would be mass storage device if it got letter assigned (e.g. D:).

Comment: @buffer: thats bummer.

Comment: seems strange that/if windows 7 can't do it though.. the android device comes up in explorer just no drive letter. indeed, android device in settings..device..storage then menu..usb computer connection only offers MTP and PTP(the nexus android phone I tested behaves like the questioners so this is how android devices are perhaps).    I would've thought windows 7 might be able to manage giving it a drive letter still.